# onCreateContextMenu

Tags: java, android

I can seen to understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    Map<String, String> data = (Map<String, String>) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String admin = preferences.getString("Admin", null);
    String user_ids = preferences.getString("userID", null);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(0, profile, 0, "Show Profile");
if (admin.equals("Admin")){ 
    menu.add(0, add, 0, "Add Friend");
    menu.add(0, pm, 0, "Send PM");
    menu.add(0, warn, 0, "Send Warning");       
    menu.add(0, edit, 0, "Edit Post");
    menu.add(0, delete, 0, "Delete Post");
    menu.add(0, block, 0, "Block User");
}else if (data.get("pid").equals(user_ids)){
    menu.add(0, edit, 0, "Edit Post");
}else{
    menu.add(0, add, 0, "Add Friend");
    menu.add(0, pm, 0, "Send PM");
    menu.add(0, warn, 0, "Send Warning");       
    menu.add(0, block, 0, "Block User");
}
 }
```

It errors out to

```
            view.showContextMenu();
```

But if I comment out the IF ELSE statements it works. Confused.

Comment: what is printed in the logcat when this error occurs?

Comment: Sorry for me, for some reason or anther it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you write

> return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

at ending of last if else condition.
and more you can see these links. [Link1](http://code.google.com/p/android-icon-context-menu/), [Link2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3QO0ffg2Tc) and [Link3](http://www.tanisoft.net/2010/09/android-context-menu-with-icon.html)

Comment: That's only for Selected I am trying to create.